# Create 1 plot from 4 different plots by face_grid in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap, facet-grid

I have the following dataframe:
[dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6IrRs.png)

I wanted to plot the two different datasets against each other, so 'total_USGS' vs 'total_WRI' 'desalination_USGS' vs 'desalination_WRI' etc.

I managed to do this in independent plots, but now I want to plot them together by using a facet_grid of facet_wrap, I searched the whole internet, but could not find a similar example.

Is it even possible?

Hope to hear from you guys.

Comment: Hi Roelalex. Nobody answered your last question because you did not provide a sample of your data. A screenshot of your data is useless because we cannot copy and paste the data to test possible solutions. Instead of posting the same question again, please edit your question to include some actual data. Try typing `dput(my_dataframe)` into the console and pasting the results into your question. It's really not possible to help you unless you do this.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I will do! I already solved this one with the help from the previous question!

Answer (score 0):

you could do a way around for plotting these graphs. As you have not provided a reproducible code, I would generally explain you what you could do.
Save the two graphs in two separate variables:

```
a <- graph code for 'total_USGS' vs 'total_WRI' 
b <- graph code for 'desalination_USGS' vs 'desalination_WRI'
```

Then you can use grid arrange to combine the plots together.

```
library(gridExtra)
grid.arrange(a, b)
```

Answer (score 0):

So first I created 4 different graphs:

`totalComparison= ggplot(stateSum) + geom_point(aes(x=total_USGS, y=total_WRI)) + geom_abline(slope=1, intercept=0, color='red') totalComparison`

`desalinationComparison= ggplot(stateSum) +  geom_point(aes(x=desalination_USGS, y=desalination_WRI)) + geom_abline(slope=1, intercept=0, color='red') desalinationComparison`

`surfacewaterComparison= ggplot(stateSum) +  geom_point(aes(x=surfacewater_USGS, y=surfacewater_WRI)) + geom_abline(slope=1, intercept=0, color='red') surfacewaterComparison`

`groundwaterComparison= ggplot(stateSum) + geom_point(aes(x=groundwater_USGS, y=groundwater_WRI)) + geom_abline(slope=1, intercept=0, color='red') groundwaterComparison`

And then I used grid.arrange to create a kind of facet wrap:

`totalGrid= grid.arrange(totalComparison, desalinationComparison, surfacewaterComparison, groundwaterComparison, ncol=2, nrow=2)`

Which then gives this:

[image]